# Template function specialization for template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, template-specialization

Is it possible to write something like this in C++11/14?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
T Get();

template <typename T>
struct Data {
    std::vector<T> data;
};

template <>
template <typename T>
Data<T> Get<Data<T>>() {
    return Data<T>{{T{}, T{}}};
}

template <>
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Get<std::vector<T>>() {
    return std::vector<T>(3);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Get<Data<int>>().data.size() << std::endl;  // expected output is 2
    std::cout << Get<std::vector<int>>().size() << std::endl; // expected output is 3
    return 0;
}
```

Overloading won't help in this case, since call to `Get<...>()` will be ambiguious ([see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e91a8e6b8b6a61f)):

```
template <typename T>
Data<T> Get() {
    return Data<T>{{T{}, T{}}};
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Get() {
    return std::vector<T>(3);
}
```

Any direction on how to overcome this are welcome.

Comment: No, we can still not partially specialize function templates. Yes, there are workarounds.

Comment: I updated my answer to adopt it to your *completely new* question. Hope there won't be any other changes, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Columbo mentioned in his comment, you should apply the standard workaround for lack of partial specialization support for functions: delegation to a partially specialized class:

```
template <typename T>
struct GetImpl;

template <typename T>
T Get() { return GetImpl<T>::Do(); }
```

and now use partial specialization on `struct GetImpl<T> { static T Do(); }` instead of `Get<T>()`

Answer (score 7):

There is workaround, that gives you something like this: do not specialize - overload:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
size_t Get(const T& data)
{
    return 444;
}

template <typename T>
struct Data
{
    std::vector<T> data;
};

template <typename T>
size_t Get(const Data<T>& data) {
    return data.data.size();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Get<>(0) << std::endl;  // expected output is 444
    std::cout << Get<>(Data<int>{}) << std::endl;  // expected output is 0
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
444
0
```

Note, that `size_t Get(const Data<T>& data)` is not a specialization - it is completely "different" `Get()`, that is called for argument of type `Data<T>` for any `T`.

[Here](http://ideone.com/2si1vw) you can see working sample.

---

**EDIT**

I see you changed your question completely. However, I will still try to answer it. There is a standard workaround for lack of partial function specialization - using delegation to structs/classes.

Here is what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct GetImpl;

template <typename T>
struct Data {
    std::vector<T> data;
};

template <typename T>
struct GetImpl< Data<T> >
{
    static Data<T> Get() {
        return Data<T>{ {T{}, T{}} };
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct GetImpl< std::vector<T> >
{
    static std::vector<T> Get() {
        return std::vector<T>(3);
    };
};

int main() {
    std::cout << GetImpl< Data<int> >::Get().data.size() << std::endl;  // expected output is 2
    std::cout << GetImpl< std::vector<int> >::Get().size() << std::endl; // expected output is 3
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
```

[Working sample can be found here.](http://ideone.com/hVEtLm)

---

If you don't like the syntax, you can make it a little bit shorter, by changing static function `Get()` to function call operator:

```
template <typename T>
struct Get< Data<T> >
{
    Data<T> operator()() {
        return Data<T>{ {T{}, T{}} };
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct Get< std::vector<T> >
{
    std::vector<T> operator()() {
        return std::vector<T>(3);
    };
};
```

And then:

```
Get< Data<int> >()().data.size();
Get< std::vector<int> >()().size();
```

You have only two extra characters - `()`. This is the shortest solution I can think of.

Comment: Is it possible to leave interface the same? So I could call `Get<Data<int>>()` , not `GetImpl<Data<int>>::Get()`?

Comment: No, you can't call it `Get<Data<int>>()`, but you can `Get<Data<int>>()()`. Se updated answer.

Comment: *"No, you can't call it Get<Data<int>>()"*, ekhm... [you can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7b5421ea28e05b7), @KostyaBazhanov fyi

Comment: @piotr-s thanks, really great usage of C++14! `auto` for the rescue!

Comment: @PiotrS. Probably the most accurate solution in this case. I didn't think of that, question was changed too many times. I suggest to post this as an answer, it's the most correct one in my opinion.

Comment: @KostyaBazhanov C++ 14 has nothing to do with it. Piotr's code is fully compatible with C++ 11.

Comment: @mateusz-grzejek yep, you are right, haven't noticed `declspec` in code. With C++14 we can leave it [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6912bc01db972456).

Comment: @KostyaBazhanov: My answer already shows the extra two lines needed to fix the interface.

Answer (score 3):

> But it would be impossible for compiler to distinguish `Get<Data<int>>` from `Get<Data<Data<int>>>`.

It's not impossible. If that's something you need to do, we can add separate overloads:

```
template <typename T>
size_t Get(const Data<T>& data);

template <typename T>
size_t Get(const Data<Data<T>>& data); // preferred for Data<Data<int>>
```

Or if what you want is to *only* overload for the non-nested case, we can add a type trait and use SFINAE:

```
template <typename T> struct is_data : std::false_type { };
template <typename T> struct is_data<Data<T>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T>
enable_if_t<!is_data<T>::value, size_t>
Get(const Data<T>& data);
```

That way, the call with `Data<Data<int>>` would call the generic `Get(const T&)`. Or, if you want that case to not compile at all:

```
template <typename T>
size_t Get(const Data<T>& data) {
    static_assert(!is_data<T>::value, "disallowed");
    ...
}
```

So overloading gives you lots of options. Specialization gives you none, since it's disallowed anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out that the question was not clear and the statement about ambiguity was wrong, since function signatures of `Length` are in fact different. Please see updated version.

Comment: @KostyaBazhanov Dude you just *completely* changed the question.

Comment: yep, oversimplified it on the first try :)

Answer (score 2):

Following delegation to the struct's way you can implement more general approach: you can use structs to check the container type and inner type like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Data {
    std::vector<T> data;
};

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename>
struct get_inner;

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename T>
struct get_inner<Container, Container<T>>
{
    typedef T type;
};




template <typename T, typename U = typename get_inner<Data, T>::type>
Data<U> Get() {
    return Data<U>{ {U{}, U{}} };
}

template <typename T, typename U = typename  get_inner<std::vector, T>::type>
std::vector<U> Get() {
    return std::vector<U>(3);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Get<Data<int>>().data.size() << std::endl;  // expected output is 2
    std::cout << Get<std::vector<int>>().size() << std::endl; // expected output is 3
    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90b55767911eff0e

Comment: Cool! The best answer so far!